# javascript / CSS - block clicking on elements (buttons) outside last opened popup and gray all outside last opened popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

when I open some popup (popup1) in the default page and I click on some button on this popup and it cause open next popup (popup2) I want to disable clicking on some element from previous popup, or in the default page while is opened last popup and gray all out of last popup. Is any possibility to do it?

I want to it looks like this...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qq07c5munojhop/popups.png

The code is long, but abbreviate code is:
CSS:

```
.popup1{
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: #fff;
}

.popup1Div {
width: 1310px;
margin: 100px auto;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #000;
padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
}

.popup2{
visibility: hidden;
z-index:10;
position:fixed;
top:50%; left:50%;
width:640px; height:480px;
margin-left:-320px; margin-top:-240px;
background-color: rgba(211,211,211,0.6);
}

.popup2 div {
 width:432px;
 height:150px;
 margin: 150px auto;
 background-color: #fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
 padding:15px;
 text-align:center;
 }
```

ASP.NET - Component of popup1 (whitch shown popup2)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="popup1UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
        <div id="popup2" class="popup2" style="visibility: hidden;">
            <div>
                ...
                <button onclick="popupVisibility(); return false;">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ASP.NET - Page code (show popup1)

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/popup1Component.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="popup1Component" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyMaster" runat="server">
    ...
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="popup1" class="popup1" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="popup1Div">
        <button style="float: right" onclick="ClosePopupWithCloseButtonOrESC(); return false;">Close</button>
        <asp:Button ID="closePopupButton" runat="server" style="visibility: hidden" Text="Close" OnClick="ClosePopupButton_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="popup1UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ... />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <uc1:popup1Component runat="server" ID="popup1Component" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and Javascript code where is setting visibility of popups after click on some buttons...

Answer (score 0):

The way i did the same last time is:

1. you create a eventHandler for the element which is opening the second popUp (onclick)
2. you're creating a div with backgournd color gray and opacity (lets say) .7 which you append to the body. Yoz give it by css full width and height. Put in z-order above all elements.
3. popup2 obviously shoud be then z-order above this div

The code should be very simple so i leave it to you.

Comment: Maybe These Elements then were in z order bwfore the div?

Comment: no, because code running on IE and order property is not supported for it... :-/

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: Well, but which ie are you using? 7?